# xcode error when download files from sandbox

Tags: ios, xcode, download, sandbox, file-exists

I save the files as .txt files using the following code:

> ```
>     FILE* file;
>     file = NULL;
>     const char *filename = [newFilePath UTF8String];
>     file = fopen(filename, "wb");
> ```

However, when I download them from the Sandbox in Organizer, a error occurred:

> Xcode has encountered an unexpected error (0xC011) File exists, at
>   ‘/SourceCache/DVTiOSFrameworks/DVTiOSFrameworks-5053/DTDeviceKitBase/DTDKApplication.m:1340’

Then only a small portion of files are downloaded.

Any one knows why and how to solve this problem?

Comment: I see the error say "File exists". Is this root cause?

Comment: That's my first thought too. However, I was not able to find that root in the Mac. @nmh

Comment: I get this using XCode6/iOS8 as well, though the "file exists" error/line number has changed: `File exists, at '/SourceCache/DVTiOSFrameworks/DVTiOSFrameworks-6254/DTDeviceKitBase/DTDKApplication.m:1505'`

Comment: I just started getting the same issue as well: `File exists, at ‘/SourceCache/DVTiOSFrameworks/DVTiOSFrameworks-6272/DTDeviceKitBase/DTDKApplication.m:1505’`

Comment: Bump...anyone have any insight into this? I'm seeing it in Xcode 6 at line 1505 as well.